# R spplot - plot points over raster with same colour scale

Tags: r, colors, grid, points, r-sp

I am trying to plot the results of a kriging with external drift, overlapping the measurement points. I would like my measurement points to be plotted with the same colour palette of the grid, and with a black border, according to the measurement value.

I can plot the points with sp.layout, but I cannot understand how to colour them according to the values with the same default colour palette of the grid.

here is what I try to do:

```
colbreaks <- seq(from=0, to=5, by=0.1)
rg <-list("sp.points", g, cex=1.5, pch=19, fill=g$rain, colourkey=TRUE)
p1 <- spplot(r, at=colbreaks, sp.layout=rg)
```

where g is a SpatialPointsDataFrame where "rain" is the value field I would like to use for the colour, and r is a SpatialGridDataFrame that contains teh result of the interpolation.

In the result the points are not coloured according to the grid palette.

any idea?

PS: I need to store the result of the spplot in the variable p because I then use it in a 2x2 grid.arrange plot with gridExtra.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If someone encounters my same problem, this is how I solved it:

Firstly I select the colour palette used by spplot:

```
colscale <- bpy.colors()
```

Then I create an index that maps my values to the corresponding colour of the colour palette. The result is a vector f of the same length of my SpatialPointsDataFrame, containing the corresponding colours. Maxrain is the maximum value associated to the end of the palette (white):

```
ind <- floor(g$rain/maxrain*(length(colscale)-1)+1)
f <- ind
f[ind>length(colscale)]<- "#FFFFFF"  # White for the exceeding values
f[is.na(ind)==F & ind<=length(colscale)] <- colscale[ind[is.na(ind)==F & ind<=length(colscale)]]
f[is.na(f)==T] <- "#444444"  # Grey for the NA
```

Then I create my lists for the sp.layout. The first set of points is only to get the black outline

```
rgb<-list("sp.points", g, cex=1.2, pch=19, col = "black", colourkey=T)
rg<-list("sp.points", g, cex=1.0, pch=19, cuts=length(g$rain), col = f, colourkey=T)
```

Finally I can use the two lists in spplot:

```
colbreaks <- seq(from=0, to=maxrain, by=0.1)    
p <- spplot(r, at=colbreaks, sp.layout=list(rgb, rg))
```

Hope it helps someone else too.
Let me know if you find a smarter and simpler way.

[This is the result of the lines above. The raster and the points have the same colour scale.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSCU6.png)